# Weak convergence of joint distributions

Tags: probability, weak-convergence

Suppose $\left(X_{n},n\in \mathbb {N}\right)$ is a sequence of iid Uni$[0,1]$ random variables. Let $M_{n}=\max\left(X_{1},\dots,X_{n}\right)$ and $N_{n}= \min\left(X_{1},\dots,X_{n}\right)$.

I've shown that for $a_{n}=b_{n}=n$, both $a_{n}\left(1-M_{n}\right)$ and $b_{n}N_{n}$ converge weakly to Exp($1$), the exponential distribution with $\lambda=1$.

Now, I wonder how to show that the sequence of joint distributions of $\left(a_{n}\left(1-M_{n}\right), b_{n}N_{n}\right)$ converges weakly as $n\to \infty$ as a sequence of probability measures on $\mathbb {R}^{2}$ equipped with the Euclidean metric. I'm not quite sure how to use the Euclidean metric here.

Comment: What about a convergence of characteristic function?

Comment: @openspace You mean a characteristic function of a joint distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Z_1 = n(1-\max(X_1,...,X_n))$ ,
$Z_2 = n(\min(X_1,...,X_n))$
For $z_1\geq 0$ and $z_2 \geq 0$,
$$P(Z_1 \geq z_1,Z_2 \geq z_2) = P(1-\frac{z_1}{n} \geq \max(X_1,...,X_n), \min(X_1,...,X_n) \geq \frac{z_2}{n})$$
$$ = P(1-\frac{z_1}{n} \geq X_1,...,X_n \geq \frac{z_2}{n})$$
$$ = \max\left(1-\frac{z_1}{n}-\frac{z_2}{n},0\right)^n$$
$$ = \max\left(1-\frac{z_1+z_2}{n},0\right)^n$$